# jQuery source for multiselect box

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, checkbox

I need to create a drop-down-menu multiple checkbox in it, like this one :

http://jobscentral.com.sg/jc/jobseeker/jobs/advancedsearch.aspx

is there any similar source ?

Comment: That's really more of a dialog popup with a bunch of checkboxes in it than an actual dropdown menu (aka `<select>`). Sam Pellino has a nice jQuery plugin linked in his answer. Take a look at the [jQuery dialog modal form example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) if you want something more customizable.

Answer (score 1):

I use the jQuery UI Multiple Select written by Eric Hynds

Easy to implement and easy to use.

See: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not a drop-down menu, but instead an image designed to look like one that executes some jquery when you click it.

I recommend you view the source of the website to try and get an idea to implement it yourself. The box that appears is simply a div with a table of checkboxes in it, that appears when you click the fake select box. Then, if you run into any problems in the implementation, ask SO again.